# Print item using pdf from html in alpha anywhere

Tags: html, printing

I have an HTML page which shows content from my CKeditor4. I'm adding a button to print the content in PDF. The best option I have is using the 'PDF from HTML' action found in alpha anywhere action.
I can generate the 'web PDF' using them. It works very well until I try to print the page.

My issue: alpha anywhere server stop unexpectedly.

Is it a bug or am I missing something?
Door open for any suggestion to print the ckeditor4 content, and where should I start my little step?

**Update:**

**I.** I am using the default configuration from alpha:
[image: print pdf from html config].

**II.** A simple HTML i wish to print: [image: data in container]

**Note:** The alpha anywhere server do not stop immediately but few seconds after the print button was clicked.

Comment: Can you provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried so far?

Comment: I realized the problem do not have anything to do with CKeditor but from the alpha anywhere action it selves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be the exact answer to this question, but it can be an alternative way to achieve the goal.
I am using the CKeditor print button in my view-only page. I set the textarea to `disable` so that user cannot alter the document, then select few button to be displayed on the CKeditor toolbar. you can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55253579/how-to-display-multiple-ckeditor-textarea-in-a-component-with-different-toolbar) to see how to have multiple CKeditor sections in a page with different toolbar button.