# How to display multiple ckeditor-textarea in a component with different toolbar?

Tags: toolbar, readonly

I have multiple ckeditor in a component and for some reason i want a textarea-ckeditor to be readonly with some toolbar enabled;

**ie:** 'print','preview','find', and 'maximize'.

How can i achieve this? i've tried removing the plugins but only success if i alter the config.js which will 'standardize' all my ckeditor.

What i can think is that i need to alter something from this code.

```
    CKEDITOR.replace('header',{
    width: '100%',
    height: 570});
```

Thanks in adv..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution but instead of removing the toolbar buttons, i list all the desired buttons as following;

```
toolbar: [
    { name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ], items: ['-','Preview', 'Print', '-' ] },
    { name: 'editing', groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ], items: [ 'Find','-','-' ] },
    { name: 'tools', items: [ 'Maximize'] }
    ]
```